# This iPad is supervised by another computer and cannot be used with this computer

Tags: ipad

I was given an iPad 2 16 GB with Wi-Fi running iOS 7.0.4. I do not know who the former owner was...I do not have a passcode...it has been wiped clean. When I turn it on it says "iPad disabled - connect to iTunes". I did that and get a message that says "This iPad is supervised by another computer and cannot be used with this computer"...I have not registered with Apple and do not have a user name. What now?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have a stolen iPad. How can you 'get' an iPad without knowing the former owner? You cannot use the iPad until you know the Apple ID that was combined with the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Restore Mode? Turn it off and start it again while it's connected to the computer. As soon as it begins startup press and hold the home button until an iTunes Symbol appears on the iPad's screen (easiest way is to turn it off and plugging it out, then holding the home button while plugging it in). Then click Restore in iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Supervise works a little differently on different OS.

An up to date summary is at:

- https://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/ior7ba06c270
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202837

Your best bet is to try to remove the profile or contact the organization that has the supervisory profile installed. If you are a school or business - you can always contact your Apple Sales person to check past purchases to validate the serial number is purchased for your organization and then get Apple Support to assist with unlocking if your MDM cannot do it.

If you don’t have a sales contact, reach out to any Apple Retail employee or education / business on the web store:

- https://www.apple.com/education/
- https://www.apple.com/business/